# Heap sort Python implementation

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, heapsort

```
def heap_sort(nos):
    global size
    size = len(nos)
    print "the size of the List is : %d " %size
    Build_heap(size,nos)
    for i in range(size-1,0,-1):
        nums[0],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[0]
        size = size-1
        print "\n", nums
        heapify(nos,i,size)
    print "heap sort array:" ,nums

def left_child(i):
    return 2*i+1

def right_child(i):
    return 2*i+2

def heapify(nums,i,size):
    l = left_child(i)
    r = right_child(i)
    if l <= size and r <= size:
        if r != size:
            if nums[l] >= nums[r]:
                max = nums[l]
                max_index = l
            elif nums[l] <= nums[r]:
                max = nums[r]
                max_index = r
            if nums[i] >= max:
                print nums
                return
            elif nums[i] <= max:
                nums[i],nums[max_index] = max,nums[i]
                heapify(nums,max_index,size)
        else:
            nums[i],nums[l] = nums[l],nums[i]
            print nums

# build a heap A from an unsorted array          
def Build_heap(size,elements):
    iterate = size//2-1
    for i in range(iterate,-1,-1):
        print "In %d iteration" %i
        heapify(elements,i,size)
    print "heapified array is : " ,elements


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #get input from user
    nums = [6,9,3,2,4,1,7,5,10]
    #sort the list
    heap_sort(nums)
```

Output which I get is something like this:

```
the size of the List is : 9 
In 3 iteration
[6, 9, 3, 10, 4, 1, 7, 5, 2]
In 2 iteration
[6, 9, 7, 10, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
In 1 iteration
[6, 10, 7, 9, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
[6, 10, 7, 9, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
In 0 iteration
[10, 6, 7, 9, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
[10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
[10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
heapified array is :  [10, 9, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2]
heap sort array: 
[9, 7, 6, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 10]
```

I tried implementing a heap sort algorithm in python. The final output is not sorted. There is something wrong in the heapify operation which I tried to figure out, but I couldn't find it.

Can someone point out what's wrong in my code and propose a solution for it?

Comment: Pro tip: Python can assign to two variables with one operation: `nums[i], nums[max_index] = max, nums[i]` and `nums[i], nums[l] = nums[l], nums[i]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first item(`0`) was swaped with the last item. To keep max-heap invairant, you should call heapify with `0`.

```
def heap_sort(nos):
    size = len(nos)
    build_heap(size,nos)
    for i in range(size-1,0,-1):
        nums[0],nums[i] = nums[i],nums[0]
        size -= 1
        heapify(nos, 0, size) # <--- i -> 0
```

Comment: why does my above code doesnt work if i give input as list of lists like  `nums = [[5,10,15,20],[6,3,16,19],[2,9,26,40],[8,22,23,24]]`

Comment: What do you want your code to produce as output? If you want `[2,3,5,6,8,9, .....]`, flatten list to 1st dimension.

Comment: suppose the above code is used to construct min-heap in k-way merge sort implementation taking k-sorted sublist as input.am storing that k-sorted sublist inside a list. In that case its not working

Answer (score 0):

The following is my PYTHON implementation. If the program is "heapsort.py", an example to run it is "python heapsort.py 10", to sort 10 randomly generated numbers.

The validation code is near the end of the program, to verify the correctness of the function, heapsort().

```
#!/bin/python
#
# TH @stackoverflow, 2016-01-20, HeapSort
#
import sys, random


def pushdown( A, root, size_of_A ):
    M = root * 2
    if(M <= size_of_A):
        if(size_of_A > M):
            if(A[M - 1] < A[M]):
                M += 1

        if(A[root - 1] < A[M - 1]):
            A[root - 1], A[M - 1] = A[M - 1], A[root - 1]
            pushdown(A, M, size_of_A)


def heapsort( H ):
    for i in range(len(H)/2, 0, -1):
        pushdown(H, i, len(H))

    for i in range(len(H) - 1, 0, -1):
        H[i], H[0] = H[0], H[i]
        pushdown(H, 1, i)

    return H


number_to_numbers = int(sys.argv[1])
X = [ random.randint(0, number_to_numbers) for i in range(number_to_numbers) ]
Y = X
print Y
print heapsort(X)
print sorted(Y)
```